# print common elements from two int arrays without repetition [beginner]

Tags: java

I'd appreciate some tips so I can get myself on the right track.
I am trying to print common values from two int arrays without repetition.  I can not use any strings, collections, extra arrays or manipulate existing arrays, and I can only use the java.lang package.

This is my code for now :

```
int[] a = { 6, 0, 2, -7, 16, 9, 1, -8, 9, 9, 3, -9, -1, 0, 1, -8, 2, 99 };
int[] b = { 16, 0, 5, 2, -5, 3, 3, 9, 9, 1, -8, -8 };


for (int x : a) {

    for (int y : b) {

        if(x == y) {
             System.out.print(x + " ");
             break;
                   }
    }
}
```

or

```
   int[] a = { 6, 0, 2, -7, 16, 9, 1, -8, 9, 9, 3, -9, -1, 0, 1, -8, 2, 99 };
   int[] b = { 16, 0, 5, 2, -5, 3, 3, 9, 9, 1, -8, -8};
   int al = a.length;
   int bl = b.length;

    for (int x = 0; x < al; x++) {

          for (int y = 0; y < bl; y++) {

            if ( a[x] == b[y] ) {

              System.out.print( a[x] + " ");
              break;
                                 }
          }
        }
```

-What prints with my current code: 0 2 16 9 1 -8 9 9 3 0 1 -8 2
-What I want to print (order might differ): 0 2 16 9 1 -8 3

An idea I had was to check the first array for duplicates using another for loop and only continue to the main loop (which checks for common elements) if it is not a duplicate, but I am not sure how to go about doing this or whether it's even doable. All my attempts of implementing this idea are failing so far.

I wrote a code snippet with the for loop that checks for duplicates (but not sure what to do with it) :

```
  int[] a = { 6, 0, 2, -7, 16, 9, 1, -8, 9, 9, 3, -9, -1, 0, 1, -8, 2, 99 };
  int[] b = { 16, 0, 5, 2, -5, 3, 3, 9, 9, 1, -8, -8};
  int al = a.length;
  int bl = b.length;


  for (int i = 0; i < al; i++) {

        for (int j = i+1; j < al ; j++) {

            // duplicates exist
            if (a[i] == a[j] ) {
            // not sure what to put here?
            }

        }
    }
```

I had multiple ideas of how I could solve this but the task rules have succeeded in forbidding all my possible solutions, please help

Comment: While links are great as *additional* source of information, they can't be *only* source of it since they can break or linked content can be changed. Use [edit] option and put task description as *text* (not an image) to the question itself.

Comment: @Pshemo thank you for the tip, I will keep that in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Iterate via a
2. We should check if such number was previously appear in a
3. If yes, ignore it
4. if no, we should check does it exist in b
5. if does, print it

Here is the code.
I didn't check it. But I think it should work. General idea is clear, I guess.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < al; i++) {
        flagDubl = false;
        //!!here I've changed your code !!
        for (int j = 0; j < i ; j++) {
            // duplicates exist
            if (a[i] == a[j] ) {
                flagDubl = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        //ignore if it is dublicate
        if (!flagDubl) {
            for (int j = 0; j < bl; j++){
                if (a[i] == b[j]) {
                    //it is in both arrays;
                    System.out.print( a[i] + " ");
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Iterate over the first array

   2. Check if the current element occurred previously in the first array

      3. If not : Check if the element occurs in the second array and if so print it.

That should prevent any duplicate values in the output.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a lazy, valid and short way, then use a data structure to store common values and use one that doesn't allow duplicates, a `Set` preferably.

In the following example, I have used a `TreeSet` because, apart from not allowing duplicate entries, it orders the values using their `compareTo` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = { 6, 0, 2, -7, 16, 9, 1, -8, 9, 9, 3, -9, -1, 0, 1, -8, 2, 99 };
    int[] b = { 16, 0, 5, 2, -5, 3, 3, 9, 9, 1, -8, -8 };

    // prepare a data structure to store the common values
    Set<Integer> commonValues = new TreeSet<>();

    // then compare each value of a to each value of b
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
            // and if they are equal,
            if (a[i] == b[j]) {
                // store one of the values in the set
                commonValues.add(a[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    // then print all the values of the set
    System.out.println("Common values of a and b (no duplicates, ordered ascending) are:");
    commonValues.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

This outputs the following:

```
Common values of a and b (no duplicates, ordered ascending) are:
-8
0
1
2
3
9
16
```